# Стилизация и анимация текста SVG

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, анимация

Хотелось бы рассмотреть ряд примеров стилизации текста и как использовать `pattern` & `mask` в связке с какими-то эффектами.

**1.** "Гусеничный" *stroke* (`linearGradient` & `animate`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**2.** Текст, отбрасывающий от себя тень из
 диагональных линий (`pattern` & `mask`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**3.** Заполнение текста водой (`SVG`(`pattern` & `mask`) & `CSS`(`@keyframes`)):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P.S.** В данном вопросе присутствуют примеры, взятые из открытого доступа(**2** и **3**). Вопрос создан с целью привлечь к `SVG` и показать его возможности.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Добавление и стилизация svg текста в растровую картинку

Необходимо добавить текст к существующей растровой картинке в стиле диалога, комикса.
При этом необходимо, чтобы изображение и текст были адаптивны,- сохраняли взаимное расположение при изменении размера.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Пошаговая инструкция:*

- Добавляем растровую картинку в `SVG`

`<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HVU6.jpg" width="400" height="300"/>`

- Рисуем в векторном редакторе контур, где будет расположен текст

  `<path  d="M350 280a400 400 0 0 0 4 -150a100 60 0 1 0 -14 4a400 400 0 0 1 10 146z"/>`
- Добавляем текст внутрь контура. К сожалению в `svg` нет автоматического
  переноса текста, как в `HTML`, но есть возможность ручного переноса
  текста с помощью атрибута `<tspan>`
- При необходимости делаем более тонкую регулировку размера, позиции
  контейнера и текста

  `<g transform="scale(1.1) translate(-40 0)" >`

```css
svg {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
}

text {
  font-family: Lobster;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-anchor: middle;
  fill: #474447;
}

path {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #474447;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="google-font.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 400 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HVU6.jpg" width="400" height="300"/>
  <g transform="scale(1.1) translate(-40 0)">
    <path stroke-miterlimit="50" d="M350 280a400 400 0 0 0 4 -150a100 60 0 1 0 -14 4a400 400 0 0 1 10 146z"/>
    <text>
      <tspan x="302" y="60">Вы вызываете</tspan>
      <tspan x="302" y="85">больше проблем,</tspan>
      <tspan x="302" y="110">чем пользы.</tspan>
    </text> 
  </g>
</svg>
```

*Картинка и текст адаптивны.

Работает во всех современных браузерах + IE11, Edge*

Comment: Интересный вариант!

Answer (score 11):

Постепенно будем рассматривать и создавать подобные примеры.

## Первый пример

1. Помещаем наш текст в `<symbol></symbol>`.

> Элемент `<symbol>` используется для определения объектов графического шаблона, которые могут быть созданы элементом `<use>`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="400" height="400">
  <symbol id="text">
    <text font-size="5em" text-anchor="middle" x="160" y="55">Some text</text>
  </symbol>
  <use xlink:href="#text"/>
</svg>
```

2. Делаем произвольный *gradient* с помощью `<linearGradient></linearGradient>`.Думаю здесь всё понятно, его можно подключать к различным элементам холста. В данном примере мы "залили" фон текста *gradient*'ом, но это не всё, что он может. Мы можем применить *gradient* для `stroke` и не только.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="400" height="400">
  <symbol id="text">
    <text font-size="5em" text-anchor="middle" x="160" y="55">Some text</text>
  </symbol>
  <linearGradient id="grad">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"/>
    <stop offset="50%" stop-color="black"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <use xlink:href="#text" fill="url(#grad)"/>
</svg>
```

3. "Нарисуем" контур для текста. Также попробуем изменять атрибут `stroke-dashoffset` с помощью `<animate/>`.

> Атрибут `stroke-dashoffset` определяет смещение `stroke` относительно начального положения
>
> Атрибут `stroke-dasharray` имеет от 2х и больше значений. Первое значение определяет длину линии, а второе - пробел между линиями

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="400" height="100">
  <symbol id="text">
    <text text-anchor="middle" x="160" y="55">Some text</text>
  </symbol>
  <linearGradient id="grad">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"/>
    <stop offset="60%" stop-color="black"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <use xlink:href="#text" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="10 15" fill="none" stroke-width="3" stroke="url(#grad)" font-size="5em">
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="250;0" dur="7s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </use>
</svg>
```

4. Можно приступать к самому "гусеничному" эффекту. Мы должны наложить текст на текст и изменить атрибуты `stroke-dashoffset` & `stroke-dasharray`.

   **Первый пример** готов:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:800);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #000000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <symbol id="stroke-dash">
    <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="50%">Stroke</text>
  </symbol>
  <linearGradient id="linear" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#05a"/>
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#0a5"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <use xlink:href="#stroke-dash" stroke="url(#linear)" stroke-dasharray="10 1" stroke-width="3" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-size="4em">
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="250;0" dur="15s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </use>
  <use xlink:href="#stroke-dash" stroke="url(#linear)" stroke-dasharray="10 15" stroke-width="3" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-size="4em">
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="250;0" dur="15s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </use>
</svg>
```

## Второй пример

**P.S.** В данном примере мы ознакомимся с `pattern` & `mask`.

1. Попробуем использовать `pattern` на любом квадрате, заполнив его кругами:

> `pattern` можно использовать в качестве заливки или обводки для различных элементов, будь то текст, фигуры или изображения.

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin+Condensed:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <circle id="circle" cx="5" cy="5" r="5" fill="#000"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="250" height="250" fill="url(#pattern)"/>
</svg>
```

2. Теперь опробуем `pattern` & `mask`.

> `mask` в нашем контексте является поверхностным слоем, который скрывает часть контента.

```css
.stripes {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  mask: url("#mask");
}

.red {
  fill: red;
}

.blue {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="150" width="150">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="strokeEffect" width="1" height="3" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(45)">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="#fff"/>
    </pattern>
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect height="100%" width="100%" style="fill: url(#strokeEffect)"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect class="stripes red" y="0"/>
  <rect class="stripes" y="50"/>
  <rect class="stripes blue" y="100"/>
</svg>
```

3. Воссоздадим второй пример, используя вышеперечисленное.

   **Второй пример** готов:

```css
body {
  background-color: #2e2e2e;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin+Condensed:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="620" height="500">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="strokeEffect" width="1" height="3" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(45)">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height=".8" fill="#ffffff"/>
    </pattern>
    <text id="text" x="250" y="100" font-size="5em" text-anchor="middle" letter-spacing="15" font-family="'Cabin Condensed'">Some text</text>
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff"/>
      <use x="-6" y="-6" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" xlink:href="#text" opacity="1" fill="#000"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <use x="6" y="6" xlink:href="#text" opacity="1" fill="url(#strokeEffect)" mask="url(#mask)"/> 
  <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#text" fill="#fff"/>
</svg>
```

## Третий пример

1. Первым делом рассмотрим код:

```css
body {
  background: #141414;
  text-align: center;
}

.water-fill {
  -webkit-animation: wave 0.7s infinite linear, fill-up 10s infinite ease-out alternate;
  animation: wave 0.7s infinite linear, fill-up 10s infinite ease-out alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wave {
  0% {
    x: -400px;
  }
  100% {
    x: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes wave {
  0% {
    x: -400px;
  }
  100% {
    x: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fill-up {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    y: 130px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 160px;
    y: -30px;
  }
}

@keyframes fill-up {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    y: 130px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 160px;
    y: -30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin+Condensed:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="575px" height="120px" viewBox="0 0 575 120" xml:space="preserve">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="water" width=".25" height="1.1" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <path fill="white" d="M0.25,1H0c0,0,0-0.659,0-0.916c0.083-0.303,0.158,0.334,0.25,0C0.25,0.327,0.25,1,0.25,1z"/>
    </pattern>
    <text id="text" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -8 117)" font-family="'Cabin Condensed'" font-size="161">LOADING</text>
    <mask id="text_mask">
      <use xlink:href="#text" fill="white"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
<rect class="water-fill" mask="url(#text_mask)" fill="url(#water)" width="1600" height="120"/>
</svg>
```

2. Делаем выводы:)

   2.1. Происходит смещение `pattern` по оси `X`.

   ---

   2.2. Эффект волны происходит за счёт ширины `rect`, которая равна `1600` и отрицательному смещению по оси `X` от `-400` до `0`. Мы можем поэкспериментировать, то есть изменить значения и посмотреть что выйдет:

   **P.S.** Результат не впечатляет, думаю вы разобрались почему так происходит. Если нет, значит вот краткий ответ: Мы делаем шире `rect`, в то время как `pattern`"подстраивается" под эту ширину, после этого мы смещаем `rect` по оси `X`.

   ---

   2.3. Далее мы вставляем его в `mask`, voilà, эффект волны для текста готов:)

```css
.water-fill {
  animation: wave 0.7s infinite linear, fill-up 10s ease-out alternate;
}

@keyframes wave {
  0% {
      /*New*/
    x: -200px;
  }
  100% {
    x: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fill-up {
  0% {
    y: 120px;
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    y: 0;
    height: 120px;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="water" width="0.25" height="1" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <path fill="dodgerblue" d="M0.25,1H0c0,0,0-0.659,0-0.916c0.083-0.303,0.158,0.334,0.25,0C0.25,0.327,0.25,1,0.25,1z"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs> 
  <!--New (width)-->
  <rect class="water-fill" fill="url(#water)" width="400" height="120"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Отлично.............

Comment: @Air, остальное не смог вместить из-за достаточно большого объема

Comment: @St1myL  Солидно. Отличные примеры. Думаю многие, кто интересуются svg, захотят повторить, что-то сделать на основе этого для  себя.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, конечно, только за, если люди будут интересоваться этим направлением:))

Comment: @St1myL, а ты закинь в `codepen` ссылку сюда....