# Как сделать эффект трещины у текста

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, анимация

> Данный Q-A является продолжением [прошлого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/803801/280567)(стилизация текста `SVG`).

В этом Q-A(Question-Answer) мы рассмотрим `Crack effect`, ниже будут приведены примеры этого эффекта, всего их будет 3 штуки.

**Первый пример** (появление трещины вдоль текста с дальнейшей трансформацией):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Второй пример** (верхняя часть текста отламывается и плавно съезжает после взмаха мечом, при том, что сам текст должен находится под наклоном примерно в `1-2deg`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Третий пример** (похож на второй, но есть своё отличие, происходит два взмаха вдоль и поперёк текста):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст будет реализован на `SVG`, его размещение через `clipPath`, а анимация с помощью `@keyframes`.

**P.S.** Все примеры срабатывают после клика.

Comment: Эти примеры на `Codepen` — https://codepen.io/St1myL/pen/KoXrRG

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Первый пример:

- Обе части текста находятся в `rect`, сам текст мы вставляем в них с
  помощью `clipPath`, а затем позиционируем их по оси `Y`, вот пример
  позиционирования первой и второй половины текста:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #000000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

svg text {
  font-family: 'Russo One', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 5em;
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Russo+One" rel="stylesheet">
<svg width="710" height="200" viewBox="0 0 710 200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip">
      <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="50%">Breaking text</text>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <rect id="top" class="rectangle" clip-path="url(#clip)" width="710" height="50" fill="white">
  <!--Смещение по оси Y-->
  <animate attributeName="y" values="-10;26;-10" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </rect>
  <rect id="bottom" class="rectangle" clip-path="url(#clip)" width="710" height="50" fill="white">
  <!--Смещение по оси Y-->
  <animate attributeName="y" values="103;75;103" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </rect>
</svg>
```

- После позиционирования текста сделаем простую анимацию, используя
  CSS-свойство - `transform` и добавим `transition`, а именно
  `cubic-bezier`. Но сначала мы пройдемся по каждому `rect`'у и дадим
  им класс `active`:

```js
function crack() {
  var rect = document.getElementsByTagName("rect");
  Array.from(rect).forEach(x => x.classList.toggle("active"));
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #000000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

svg text {
  font-family: 'Russo One', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 5em;
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}

svg rect {
  transition: cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 1) .1s;
}

rect.active {
  transform: translateX(-3px) rotate(-0.15deg);
}

rect.active:last-child {
  transform: translateX(3px) rotate(0.15deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Russo+One" rel="stylesheet">
<svg width="710" height="200" viewBox="0 0 710 200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip">
      <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="50%">Breaking text</text>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g onclick="crack()">
    <rect id="top" class="rectangle" clip-path="url(#clip)" width="710" height="50" y="26" fill="white"/>
    <rect id="bottom" class="rectangle" clip-path="url(#clip)" width="710" height="50" y="75" fill="white"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 15):

## Второй пример:

- В этом примере используется то же самое позиционирование, только в
  добавок нужно повернуть `rect`'ы на `1deg` и после клика добавлять
  `transform: translateX(N)`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #000000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

svg text {
  font-family: 'Russo One', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 4em;
  pointer-events: none;
}

svg rect {
  transform: rotate(-1deg);
  transition: cubic-bezier(1, 0.3, 0.6, 1) 3.5s;
}

#top { 
  animation: offsetXF 1s infinite;
}

#bottom { 
  animation: offsetXT 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes offsetXF {
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-30px) rotate(-1deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes offsetXT {
  50% {
    transform: translateX(30px) rotate(-1deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Russo+One" rel="stylesheet">
<svg viewBox="0 0 710 200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip">
      <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="49%">Breaking text</text>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g>
  <!--Смещение по оси X-->
    <rect id="top" clip-path="url(#clip)" width="710" height="50" y="26" fill="white"/>
    <rect id="bottom" clip-path="url(#clip)" width="710" height="50" y="75" fill="white"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

- Осталось сделать `polygon`, который будет имитировать взмах мечом(или катаной:D), а в финальной версии этого примера мы будем смещать его также по оси `X`, примерно на `700-800px`:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 710 200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <polygon id="sword" points="0,75 55,67 70,75 56,80" fill="silver" transform="scale(2)"/>
</svg>
```

- Финальная версия. После клика мы меняем местоположение `polygon`, при
  этом добавляется класс для `#top`, из-за чего и происходит смещение верхней части текста, также видна задержка после взмаха, так как у `rect` добавлен
  `transition-delay`:

```js
function crack() {
  var rect = document.getElementById("top");
  var polygon = document.getElementById("sword");
  rect.classList.add("active");
  polygon.classList.add("_activate");
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #000000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

svg text {
  font-family: 'Russo One', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 4em;
  pointer-events: none;
}

svg rect {
  transform: rotate(-1deg);
  transition: cubic-bezier(1, 0.3, 0.6, 1) 3.5s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

#top.active {
  transform: translateX(-30px) rotate(-1deg);
  opacity: 0;
}

#sword {
  transform: rotate(-1deg) translateX(-100px);
}

#sword._activate {
  animation: attack 0.4s 1;
}

@keyframes attack {
  to {
    transform: rotate(-1deg) translateX(750px);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Russo+One" rel="stylesheet">
<svg viewBox="0 0 710 200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip">
      <text text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="49%">Breaking text</text>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g onclick="crack()">
    <rect id="top" clip-path="url(#clip)" width="710" height="50" y="26" fill="white"/>
    <rect clip-path="url(#clip)" width="710" height="50" y="75" fill="white"/>
    <polygon id="sword" points="0,75 55,67 70,75 56,80" fill="silver"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: почему-то финальная версия во всех примерах не работает в лисе как минимум

Answer (score 12):

## Третий пример:

- Вместо двух `rect` мы будем использовать четыре, для каждых двух
  частей я сделал по `clipPath`( не нашёл способа лучше, буду рад
  предложениям, как сделать это "чище":) ):
  **P.S.** Примерно то, что мы должны получить.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #000000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

svg rect {
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-30 0 740 200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <!-- FOUR RECTS -->
  <g>
    <rect clip-path="url(#clip)" width="336" height="50" y="26">
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" values="0 0; -20 -20; 0 0" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </rect>
    <rect clip-path="url(#clip)" width="336" height="50" y="75">
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" values="0 0; -20 20; 0 0" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </rect>
    <rect clip-path="url(#clip)" width="336" height="50" x="336" y="26">
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" values="0 0; 20 -20; 0 0" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"/> 
    </rect>
    <rect clip-path="url(#clip)" width="336" x="336" height="50" y="75">
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" values="0 0; 20 20; 0 0" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"/> 
    </rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

- Все три примера между собой похожи, поэтому нет надобности повторно
  говорить, что к имитации взмаха и к остальным `rect`( не сочтите за
  лень:))) ) добавляются классы, собственно  вот, воззрите:

```js
function doubleCrack() {
  var rect = document.getElementsByTagName("rect");
  var polygon = document.getElementById("horizontal");
  var polygonTwo = document.getElementById("vertical");

  polygon.classList.add("_activate");
  polygonTwo.classList.add("_activate");

  Array.from(rect).forEach(x => x.classList.add("_activate-rect"));
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #000000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

svg text {
  font-family: "Russo One", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 5em;
  pointer-events: none;
}

svg rect {
  transition: 2s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  fill: white;
}

#horizontal {
  transform: translateX(-100px);
}

#vertical {
  transform: translate(335px, 150px);
}

#horizontal._activate {
  animation: attack 0.4s 1;
}

#vertical._activate {
  animation: attack-2 0.4s 1;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

#top._activate-rect {
 transform: translate(-20px, -20px);
 opacity: 0;
}

#bottom._activate-rect {
 transform: translate(-20px, 20px);
 opacity: 0;
}

#topN._activate-rect {
 transform: translate(20px, -20px);
 opacity: 0;
}

#bottomN._activate-rect {
 transform: translate(20px, 20px);
 opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes attack {
  to {
    transform: translateX(750px);
  }
}

@keyframes attack-2 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(335px) translateY(-150px);
  }
}

@keyframes break {
  to {
    transform: translateX(320px);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Russo+One" rel="stylesheet">
<svg viewBox="0 0 740 200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <!-- FIRST SIDE -->
    <clipPath id="clip">
      <text text-anchor="middle" x="368" y="50%">Breaking text</text>
    </clipPath>
    <!-- SECOND SIDE -->
    <clipPath id="clipN">
      <text text-anchor="middle" x="370" y="50%">Breaking text</text>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <!-- FOUR RECTS -->
  <g onclick="doubleCrack()">
    <rect id="top" clip-path="url(#clip)" width="336" height="50" y="26"/>
    <rect id="bottom" clip-path="url(#clip)" width="336" height="50" y="75"/>
    <rect id="topN" clip-path="url(#clipN)" width="380" height="50" x="335" y="26"/>
    <rect id="bottomN" clip-path="url(#clipN)" width="380" height="50" x="335" y="75"/>
  </g>
  <!-- SWORDS -->
  <g>  
    <polygon id="horizontal" points="0,75 55,67 70,75 56,80" fill="silver"/>
    <polygon id="vertical" points="0,60 5,68 0,100 -5,68" fill="silver"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```