# Не подключается шрифт к SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

```html
<svg height='100' width='100' viewBox='-3 -3 100 100' xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <style>
        .polylogobox {
           fill: #ef402a;
           transition: .2s;
         }
         .polylogobox:hover {
           fill: #fff;
           stroke: #ef402a;
           stroke-width: 3px;
         }
         .polylogobox:hover + text {
           fill: #ef402a;
         }
         .logoletter {
           font-size: 26px;
           fill: white;
           font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
           transition: .2s;
         }
         .logoname {
           font-size: 32px;
           fill: white;
         }
      </style>
      <polygon class='polylogobox' points='22,0 44,0 48,6 72,6 72,46 22,46' />
      <text class='logoletter' x='38' y='36'>E</text>
      <text class='logoname' style='font-family: "Open-Sans", Arial;' x='6' y='94'>Expire</text>
    </svg>
```

Есть такой `SVG` код, нужно что бы текст под самой иконкой был определенного шрифта.
 В `Google` подсказывают добавлять инлайн стилем `font-family`, однако такой способ не привел ни к чему хорошему, шрифт не отображается.
Сам `SVG` логотип добавлен в таком виде в каком есть, т.е. вставлен напрямую в код `svg` тегом. Была попытка вставить в тег `style` в самом `svg` элементе нужный шрифт, но и так не получилось.
 Пытался в главном `css-файле` страницы прописать стили для `svg text`, и это не помогло. Причем шрифт 100% подключен к странице, т.к. на других элементах работает.

Как правильно подключать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот посмотрите пример, где решалась аналогичная задача, подключения текста внутри блока svg - [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/803888/28748)

Я добавил рукописный шрифт, чтобы было явно видно, что он подключился. Вы можете выбрать любой другой [гугловский шрифт](https://fonts.google.com/) и подключить по аналогии с примером.

```css
.polylogobox {
   fill: #ef402a;
   transition: .2s;
 }
 .polylogobox:hover {
   fill: #fff;
   stroke: #ef402a;
   stroke-width: 3px;
 }
 .polylogobox:hover + text {
   fill: #ef402a;
 }
 .logoletter {
   font-size: 26px;
   fill: white;
   
   transition: .2s;
 }
 .logoname {
   font-size: 32px;
   fill: black;
   font-family: Lobster;
 }
 
 .logoname:hover {
   fill: #fff;
   stroke: #ef402a;
   stroke-width: 1px;
```

```html
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="google-font.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 

<svg height='100' width='100' viewBox='-3 -3 100 100' xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="border:1px solid red;">
 
<polygon class='polylogobox' points='22,0 44,0 48,6 72,6 72,46 22,46' />
 <text class='logoletter' x='38' y='36'>E</text>
  <text class='logoname'  x='6' y='90'>Expire</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: А если мне нужно подключить из папки шрифты, не используя гугл фонтс, как мне быть? Нужно получается прописывать подключение шрифтов непосредственно внутри тега <style> в svg?. Я имею ввиду @font-face: .....

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi сейчас идёт какой-то переходный период в браузерах,  font-face не всегда срабатывает в svg, более надёжно, как в моем примере делать, тем более вы указали шрифт, который есть у google https://fonts.google.com/?query=Open+Sans

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi если вы обратили внимание шрифт подключен из внешней таблицы css, поэтому всегда легко его заменить в ней и не нужно будет менять шрифт в каждом svg  А насчёт шрифтов из папки, это ведь решение только для локального ПК. Для сетевого варианта, нет уверенности, что у пользователя окажется тот же шрифт на ПК, что и у вас на ПК

Comment: но ведь шрифты скачиваються с сервера, если подключать с помощью font-face. Я не очень хочу подключать с помощью google fonts потому что он иногда лагает, и сайт просто не может загрузиться.

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi я не спорю, просто пытаюсь понять. То есть вы считаете, что ваш сервер, где находится ваш сайт, надежнее и быстрее и более устойчив, чем сервера google? Ведь, чтобы использовать шрифты, пользователь их будет скачивать с вашего сервера, который в разы медленнее и менее надёжен.

Comment: ну да, вы правы, все же, если, например шрифта нет на гугл фонтс? Можно же использовать font-face внутри стилей самого SVG?

Comment: <link href="google-font.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
Что это за строка, и что должно быть в этом файле?

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi это стандартные строчки подключения шрифта google, копируйте один к одному/ делайте строго пример 1:1 и у вас всё получится.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZxZqPY - Код
http://prntscr.com/j4aifo - Ошибка

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi а у меня работает ваш пример 
 -https://codepen.io/Alexandr_T/pen/bvJOqB вы неправильно указали имя шрифта надо было указать  font-family: 'Lobster' codepen сегодня тормозит, дождитесь

Comment: мне эти строки добавлять в основной html или в файл svg?  Получаю такие результаты http://prntscr.com/j4defe
http://prntscr.com/j4dem3 http://prntscr.com/j4deps

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi строки подключения  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="google-font.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">  в Html файл.. и это ... вожусь. вожусь с вашим вопросом а положительной реакции не вижу

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi , Букву "Е" желательно тоже :hover сделать, а то мышь, находясь на ней, вновь возвращает первоначальный цвет папочки...

Answer (score 2):

Проблема не в шрифтах.
как видим из исходника - у автора вопроса стиль шрифта прописан лишь для буквы "E", поскольку лишь эта буква находится внутри класса `.logoletter`.
Цитирую:

```
.logoletter {  
  font-size: 26px;  
  fill: white;  
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;  
  transition: .2s;  
}
```

А слово `Expire` принадлежит ко классу `.logoname`  и окрашено тем же цветом, что и фон:

```
.logoname {  
  font-size: 32px;  
  fill: white;  
}
```

Разумеется, что белое на белом не будет видно, (какой бы шрифт не применяли), пока мы не добавим к тексту класса `.logoname` некий "бордер" другого цвета и/или не перекрасим цвет текста с помощью `fill`, как это сделал Александр:

```
.logoname {  
  font-size: 32px;  
  fill: black;  
  font-family: Lobster;  
}  

.logoname:hover {  
  fill: #fff;  
  stroke: #ef402a;  
  stroke-width: 1px;  
}
```

Примеры Александр уже выложил, поэтому нет необходимости дублировать их ещё раз.