# Какие есть способы подключить шрифт к SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

Есть такой SVG файл.

```html
<svg height='100' width='100' viewBox='-3 -3 100 100' xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    .polylogobox {
      fill: #ef402a;
      transition: .2s;
    }
    .polylogobox:hover {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: #ef402a;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }
    .polylogobox:hover + text {
      fill: #ef402a;
    }
    .logoletter {
      font-size: 26px;
      fill: white;
      font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
      transition: .2s;
    }
    .logoname {
      font-size: 32px;
      fill: white;
    }
  </style>
  <polygon class='polylogobox' points='22,0 44,0 48,6 72,6 72,46 22,46' />
  <text class='logoletter' x='38' y='36'>E</text>
  <text class='logoname' x='6' y='94'>Expire</text>
</svg>
```

К странице html он подключается посредством тега `object`.

Появился вопрос, какие есть способы подключить свой шрифт к этому svg файлу?

Мне ранее уже отвечали на этот вопрос, но когда я попробовал сам, у меня не вышло.

[Первый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/808526/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82-%D0%BA-svg)

Когда я добавил `link` в svg файл, то у меня выбило ошибку. Пробовал гуглить, ничего толкового по этому поводу - нет.

Comment: Нашёл причину и добавил разъяснение в первоначальном варианте вопроса.

Answer (score -1):

Вы прописали стили. Что мешает прописать правила для подключения (загрузки) шрифтов через `@font-face`? 
Если пытались подключить стили через тег `link` в файл `svg`, то наверное вы забыли его закрыть по правилам XML.

`<link href="fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" />`