# Бегущая пунктирная рамка у блока

Tags: css, svg, анимация, css-animation

Как сделать так, чтобы граница блока была не статичной, а бегала по направлению часовой стрелки? Понимаю, что как-то должно быть с помощью css animation... Не даётся мне это свойство никак :-(

```
.links_wrapper2 {
    height: 165px;
    margin: 5px 0 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border: dashed 1px #537098;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

<div class="links_wrapper2">Контент</div>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа)

Answer (score 6):

**Вариант на `CSS`:**

*Смещаем `background-image` с помощью `background-position`*

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.main {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(0, white 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(0, white 50%, transparent 50%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-y, repeat-y;
  background-size: 8px 3px, 8px 3px, 3px 8px, 3px 8px;
  animation: running-contour 0.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes running-contour {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0, 8px 100%, 0 8px, 100% 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 8px 0, 0 100%, 0 0, 100% 8px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
```

**Вариант на `SVG`:**

*Подобная анимация есть в этом QA —* [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/803801/280567)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<svg width="104" height="104" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <rect x="2" y="2" width="100" height="100" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="4" stroke-dashofsset="250" stroke-dasharray="15">
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="150;0" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </rect>
</svg>
```